# Processing SSAS cube through XMLA

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I have little knowledge on SSAS cube processing through XMLA code and would need help here.
I am processing the cube through below code.

```
<Object>
  <DatabaseID>DB_test</DatabaseID>
  <CubeID>Test</CubeID>
  <MeasureGroupID>Order</MeasureGroupID>
  <PartitionID>Order 1</PartitionID>
```

ProcessFull
    UseExisting

So I wanted to know if this code only process partition as the hierarchy that I am giving is Cube --> MeasureGroup --> partition.

If so, what should I need to do process full cube, do I need to add something like below to my query.

```
<object>    
  <DatabaseID>DB_test</DatabaseID>
  <CubeID>Test</CubeID>
</Object>
<Type>ProcessFull</Type>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by reading this great [whitepaper](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345142(v=sql.90).aspx).

You are correct about the XMLA needed to ProcessFull your cube object but that won't process any dimensions.

If the following is fast enough then just do a ProcessFull on the database (which processes dimensions and cubes):

```
<Batch Transaction="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Process>
    <Object>
      <DatabaseID>DB_test</DatabaseID>
    </Object>
    <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
  </Process>
</Batch>
```

Comment: The paper helped me.. Thanks..! What I understood is that by specifying the hierarchy for example Cube -- measure -- partition, it does process only partition, the other measures needs to be processed, in other words there should a XMLA code to process other parts of the cube.